Number of labels in facebook / detr-resnet-50 model
I am preparing to train a Facebook ResNet DETR model on a custom dataset for detecting signatures in images (I have only 1 class in my dataset). I'm uncertain about the appropriate value to assign to the num_labels parameter in the model configuration. Given the context, should this value be set to 1 (since I'm only detecting signatures), or I should add the 2nd label for the cases where there is no any signatures?
Here is the code
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=CHECKPOINT,num_labels=????,ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

Usually for object detection you should put two. Background and classes so always your number of classes + 1

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
